# How to get contact key in MobileConnect SMS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Want to do a DE lookup by passing contact key in an SMS. How to get 'contact key' or 'contact id' in MobileConnect SMS?

```
%%[ 
   SET @result = LookupRows("CustomerMobile","ContactID", **CONTACT_KEY**) 
]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the AMPscript that you provided will return a rowset, which isn't what you want.

If you just want to use the Contact ID for the mobile subscriber, you can simply use the personalization string `%%_ContactID%%`.

If you want to retrieve a field from your 'CustomerMobile' Data Extension based on the ContactID at send time, then you can use:

```
%%[ 
var @result
set @result = Lookup("CustomerMobile", "NameOfFieldToReturn", "ContactID", _ContactID)
]%%
```